# Reading a data file with labels as a distance matrix in R

Tags: r, text, matrix, distance, hierarchical-clustering

I'm new to R. I have a distance matrix in a text file, for example genome sequences of animals, like so:

```
cat 0.40 0.80 0.90
dog 0.80 0.35 0.85
bat 0.90 0.85 0.38
```

I want to read this file as a `dist` object, so I can pass it to `hclust` and plot a dendrogram (with labels).

What is the best way to do this? I tried converting a matrix to a dist, but I get behaviour I don't understand:

```
# The above matrix, without labels
A <- matrix( c(0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.35, 0.85, 0.9, 0.85, 0.38), nrow=3)
as.dist(A)
#      1    2
# 2 0.80     
# 3 0.90 0.85
```

I only want to change the class of the data structure, not do operations on it.

How to pass the data in the text file to hclust, with labels?

Comment: What are the column names? Normally we'd expect the diagonal to be 0 if the column names are the same as row names...

Comment: The column names are the same as the row names, but the distance from an object to itself is not 0 under this metric.

Comment: May be `as.dist(A, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE)`

Comment: That still changes A, which is not my intention. The distance matrix is already in the text file.

Comment: @Geert Sorry, I didn't understand your expected result, then

Comment: What `hclust` method would not ignore the diagonal? I guess you could set class and attributes to that of a `dist` ob manually, but...

Comment: I do not want to ignore the diagonal. I want to pass the data in the text file to hclust, as is. If I could, I would just do `hclust(A)`, where `A` is the matrix obtained from the text file.

Comment: `hclust` expects an object made with `dist`, but the latter, to my knowledge, will always produce a matrix with 0's as diagonal. And manually forcing the class of A to be "dist" will not work. Can you elaborate a bit more on the type of data (you mentionned a metric in a previous comment, what would that be)?

Comment: If the distance matrix is asymmetric, then the measure no longer is a distance. All clustering methods in `hclust()` expect a distance. There are other clustering methods that are usable for asymmetric matrices, such as Taylor-Butina and spectral clustering. These might or not have a suitable implementation in R (such as `kernlab::specc()`). However, these methods take a simple matrix instead of an distance matrix as an input.

Comment: I'm using a metric called normalized compression distance, which is an information distance between two files. It is computed by comparing the compressed length of two files separately and the compressed length of the concatenation of the files, using a common compressor like zlib. @JTT, could you please elaborate? I'm kinda new to the subject of clustering, I thought symmetry was not needed. Many clustering methods seem to use the lower triangle of the matrix anyway.

Comment: Hmm, my bad, I might have previously misread the distance matrix to be asymmetric, but now it certainly seems to be symmetric (cat->dog distance is equal to dog->cat distance ). Oh well, it makes things even easier. Function `hclust()` does not really use diagonal distances for anything, so converting the data from the text file into a distance matrix doesn't really lose anything (see e.g. http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~re1u06/teaching/upgma/ for an example). For example, `hclust(as.dist(A))` should suffice.